# Distribute all @Test methods among various already invoked browsers

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I would like to define number of browsers (Threads) to be invoked in testng.xml and distribute n-number of test cases among all invoked browsers.
i.e., if suppose before executing if i defined thread-count as 10 for suite tag and i have 100 methods or data-provider data then among these 10 browsers all 100 methods should be distributed(assuming 2 test methods per browser) without opening any new browsers . How can we achieve this using testng with java?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not very clear. When you say `10 browsers` what do you mean ? Are you talking about `10 instances of the same browser flavor` (or) are you talking about `10 instances of different browsers` ? If its the latter one, then what are those different flavors ?

Comment: Hi Krishnan,  case 1: I would like to invoke same browser flavour i.e., if 3 browsers are invoked beginning of suite then all testcases should be distributed among these available browsers without opening or invoking any new browsers in between.Case 2: same as case 1 but with different browser flavours(chrome,firefox,IE) are invoked only once at beginningof suite

Comment: You would need to add more context than just telling your use cases. You would need to show us what code you have for this. Where are you stuck ?